# Get Max aggregations for multiple columns in pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and want to groupby one column, "Company" and aggregate multiple columns and find the company with the max value for each aggregated column.

```
  Company   performed    Requests     Request_Id  Num_of_refunds
0  A         7             60          U9             3
1  A         90            6           U10            2
2  B         89            6           ZX9            10
3  B         2             3           OOF            9         
4  B         22            0           LQI            4 
5  D         7             5           QW             3
6  D         87            2           XB             5
```

I want to use a groupby with multiple aggregations that
sums "performed", "Requests", "Num_of_refunds" and
counts "Request_Id"

I want the Company name with the max of each sum and count aggregation returned

```
performed    Requests     Request_Id  Num_of_refunds
 max          max          max           max
 B: 103       A: 66        B: 3          B: 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `sum` if numeric columns and `count` if strings, then get `Company` by maximum values by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and merge with `max` converted to `string`s, last if necessary convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.count()
df1 = df.groupby('Company').agg(f)
print (df1)
         performed  Requests  Request_Id  Num_of_refunds
Company                                                 
A               97        66           2               5
B              113         9           3              23
D               94         7           2               8

df2 = (df1.idxmax() + ': ' + df1.max().astype(str)).to_frame().T
print (df2)
  performed Requests Request_Id Num_of_refunds
0    B: 113    A: 66       B: 3          B: 23
```

Comment: Im getting a NotImplementedError: axis other than 0 is not supported

Comment: @TH14 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: im running on python 3.7 and pandas '0.23.4'

Comment: yes it is! thank you so much. What is the .T at the end?

Comment: @TH14 - It is [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) - transpose function

Comment: oh okay awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Company']).agg({'performed':'sum'
    , 'Requests':'sum'
    , 'Num_of_refunds':'sum'
    ,'Request_Id':'count'})
```